# An Extra Character At the End of Char Array (char *Result = new char) 8OI

Tags: c++, visual-c++, directx, directx-9

I have a C++ function that splits LPSTR type variable an attact it into an char array (char*)
 Example:

```
this->XMeshTexturePath = FindTexturePath(XMeshTexturePath,d3dxMaterials[i].pTextureFilename);
   //the value of XMeshTexturePath is: Models\\Textures\\
   //the value of d3dxMaterials[i].pTextureFilename is: BlaBlaBla\\BlaBla\\Cyrex.x
   //The Result(XMeshTexturePath) should be like this:"Models\\Textures\\Cyrex.x"
```

This is the funcion I'm trying to write:

```
int FindTextLength(char* Text){
    int length
```

h=0;
        for(int i=0;i

```
char* FindTexturePath( char* TexturePath ,LPSTR FileNameToCombine){
    int FileLength=0;
    int PathAndFileLength=0;
    char *FileName = new char;
    char *TexPathAndName = new char;

    strcpy(TexPathAndName, FileNameToCombine);
    PathAndFileLength = FindTextLength(TexPathAndName);

    for(int i=0; i<PathAndFileLength; i++){
        if( TexPathAndName[i] != NULL){
            if(TexPathAndName[i] != '\\'){
                FileName[FileLength] = TexPathAndName[i];
                FileLength++;
            }
            else 
                FileLength = 0 ;
        }else break;
    }

    int PathLength = FindTextLength(TexturePath);
    char *Result = new char;
//==============>> // I also tryed this:char *Result = new char[PathLength+FileLength];
//==============>> //                   char *Result = new char();

    for(int i=0; i<PathLength; i++){
        if( TexturePath[0] != NULL){
            Result[i] = TexturePath[i];
        }
        else break;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<FileLength; i++){
        if( FileName[0] != NULL){
            Result[PathLength + i] = FileName[i];
        }
        else break;
    }

    return **Result**; // The Problem is here It should be like this:
                       // "Models\\Textures\\Cyrex.x"
                       // But I'm taking one of these as result:
                       //    "Models\\Textures\\Cyrex.x{"
                       //    "Models\\Textures\\Cyrex.xu"
                       //    "Models\\Textures\\Cyrex.xY"
                       //    The last character is random... 8O(
}
```

Actualy it's not wokring so bad. The problem is when I declare an char array(**char *Result = new char;**) it does'not metter how much is length I'm takin an extra character at the end of final result(**Result**)
I'm realy stucked in here if you have any idea or suggestion plase let me know. 
Thanks for any advice and respons.

> The Solusion is adding this at the end
>   of function:

```
            Result[i] = TexturePath[i];
        }
        else break;
    }

    for(int i=0; i<FileLength; i++){
        if( FileName[0] != NULL){
            Result[PathLength + i] = FileName[i];
        }
        else break;
    }
    Result[PathLength+FileLength] = '\0' ;  // This part is resloving the problem.
                                            // **Thanks for helps**.
    return Result;
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
char *Result = new char[PathLength+FileLength];
```

`Result` pointed data should end with the termination character `\0`. Or you will run into problems when returned such a string pointed by `Result`. So,

```
Result[PathLength+FileLength-1] = '\0' ;
```

Make sure you never overrun the buffer or even a better option is to use `std::string`.

Comment: Of course, `PathLength` and `FileLength` should be initialized properly prior to doing this.

Comment: That's the answer! I just added that termination character just before return the Result variable. And it's working just perfect thank you for information.

Comment: Don't you need PathLenght+FileLenght+1? For the null terminator?

Comment: @PsyCoder - See the edit please. What @Coder mentioned is very important.

Answer (score 1):

`new char` allocates space for a single character. You probably mean to allocate space for an array of characters, which you can do with `new char[N]` where N is the size of the array (e.g. `new char[40]`)

Answer (score 0):

```
char *FileName = new char;
char *TexPathAndName = new char;
```

That should crash. You're allocating 1-character buffers, then trying to strcpy into them, which is clearly going to overflow those buffers pretty quickly. Also, remember that after the characters in the string you need 1 extra space for the null terminator.

Comment: I accept your information. But when I begin directX programming I saw too much imposible things such as this :D It's realy not crushing :P Also thank you for your time.

Comment: If that doesn't crash, it's because you're getting lucky, not because it's correct.

Comment: It's crashed as you said. I'm not using it anymore :)

Answer (score 0):

Best approach is to use `std::string`.

If you don't, for string length there are functions like strlen/wcslen. Windows shell has also some very handy functions for path manipulation http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb773559%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Most of them can come handy, and usually you manipulate static length `char path[MAX_PATH]={}` buffers.

Remember that max path is 256 or so, for deeper nested folders there are some problems.